# global startup and shutdown events when application starts and exist

Tags: vb.net

I need to write a log when the application starts and exits. Obviously when it starts it easy to write the log. But a user can close an application in multiple ways, even shut it down in task manager. is there sort of a global event when shutting an application down it will call a specific event from anywhere and I can add my logging code?

Comment: if your app starts from a Main Form, you can do it in the `FormClosing` event.  If your app exits from 'when last form closes' then you may need to add code to all the FormClosing events to look at the reason to determine whether to make the log entry.

Answer (score 1):

In visual Studio, go to the project properties window, Application tab. AT the bottom is a button labelled 'View Application Events' This takes you to a code view where you can add handlers for the application events including the shutdown event. However, this isn't *always* fired if your application crashes ^H^H^H^H^H closes in an 'unusual' way.

The startup event is useful too - you could put your startup logging code in there- we use it a lot to put in all the application setup code, with only a splash screen showing, then when the startup code completes the main window will pop up.

Finally, the Unhandled Exception event is a handy place to put a final catch-all backstop error handler

Comment: After clicking the "View Application Events" button, use the two dropdowns across the top of the editor window.  Change the Left one to "(MyApplication Events)", and the Right one to "Starup" or "Shutdown".